# After posting a form going to a new view Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect to another page after posting all the data to the database. I got it to post the data without going to another view but now I have added the view it wont do either and i get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Here is my routes.php file

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


Route::Get('/', function()
{
    return View::Make('welcome');
});

Route::Get('registration', function()
{
    return View::make('registration');
});


Route::post('registration', function()
{
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->UserName = Input::get('UserName');
    $user->Password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->FirstName = Input::get('FirstName');
    $user->LastName = Input::get('LastName');
    $user->Gender = Input::get('Gender');
    $user->Email = Input::get('Email');
    $user->Q1 = Input::get('Q1');
    $user->Q2 = Input::get('Q2');
    $user->Q3 = Input::get('Q3');
    $user->save();
    return View::make('welcomepage');
});
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a modified `route.php`. It redirects the user to a page called `registrationsuccess` after saving the user to the DB. Is it that what you want?
Note: You need to a template under `resources/views/registrationsuccess.blade.php` with the content you want to show after a successful registration.

```php
// Welcome page
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::Make('welcome');
});

// Registration GET, with empty form
Route::get('registration', function()
{
    return View::make('registration');
});

// Registration POST, with form content
Route::post('registration', function()
{
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->UserName = Input::get('UserName');
    $user->Password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->FirstName = Input::get('FirstName');
    $user->LastName = Input::get('LastName');
    $user->Gender = Input::get('Gender');
    $user->Email = Input::get('Email');
    $user->Q1 = Input::get('Q1');
    $user->Q2 = Input::get('Q2');
    $user->Q3 = Input::get('Q3');
    $user->save();
    return redirect('registrationsuccess');
});

// Success page after registration
Route::get('welcomepage', function()
{
    return view('welcomepage');
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work! I really cannot work out where the problem is. I changed registrationsuccess to welcomepage and still no luck

Comment: Ok, I changed it in my code sample. Is it like that in your `route.php` and you are still getting the same `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` error? Can you post a bigger stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to clear the cache and tried it again and it worked!

Comment: @Jeigh Glad to hear that! Please mark the post as solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/` route, your Make method should be in small letters..

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Same can be said for `Route::Get()` instead of `Route::get()`;

Comment: this doesn't seem to make any difference when I changed that

Comment: The 'welcome' is the standard route used I am trying to direct to 'welcomepage'

Comment: Did you add a 'welcomepage' template? The route / returns the 'welcome' template, the route post:registration returns 'welcomepage' template.

Comment: @codedge I'm guessing you mean in my public folder then yes. If I make the route on its own i can direct to it but just not after the form submission.

Comment: @Jeigh Can you post a screenshot of your resources/view folder so that we can see the template structure?

Comment: The template for the file is there. I can access it if i add this to the routes,php:

`Route::get('welcomepage', function()
{
return View::make('welcomepage');
});
`
and then going to localhost:8000/welcomepage but not after posting

Comment: Another thing: You do not redirect to another route after saving the user. You just display a new template, is that correct? Just asking because you wrote `I am trying to redirect to another page after posting all the data to the database.` If you want to redirect you should add i. e. `return redirect('/');`after saving your user.

Comment: I think I may be slightly confused. Basically after the registration page I want to go to another page. Would this be using `return redirect` then? I have tried this and it also doesn't seem to work